# Could not load the specified file. (itextsharp.LicenseKey)

Tags: itext

So I am using free itextsharp version over my .net core 2.1 project and I start getting the following exception:

```
Message: Could not load the specified file. FileName: itextsharp.LicenseKey
Stack Trace:    at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingEvent(AssemblyName assemblyName)    
                at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingResolvingEvent(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
```

My question is if I am really missing a licence key, where I can get  licence key for the  free version of the application?

Comment: Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: I tired over both the latest  and over 4.1.6

Comment: What is the version number of the latest you used? Because the latest released version of iText for .NET is 7.1.3 and I want to make sure. Different iText versions require different License Key Libraries.

Comment: the last installed version from nuget was 5.5.13

Comment: The latest version of iText on NuGet is https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/7.1.3

Comment: do i need it after i installed the ITextsharp  5.5.13 ?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't run into that error at all if you used 5.5.13 without using any feature that requires a license. Thus, please show the relevant code causing that error.